# Sort 'dot' separated list of string values in a data structure using Java

Tags: java, data-structures

Please consider the following dataset, which is a list of `String`.
`{"20.01","20.01.01","20.01.01.01","20.01.02","20.01.02.01","20.01.02.02","20.02","20.02.01","20.02.01.01","20.02.02","20.02.02.01","20.02.02.02","20.02.02.02.01","20.02.02.02.01.01","20.02.02.02.02","20.02.02.02.03"}`

I want to organize it a tree based data structure using Java. My expected output will look like as follows: 

`20.01 
    20.01.01 
        20.01.01.01 
    20.01.02 
        20.01.02.01 
        20.01.02.02 
20.02 
    20.02.01 
        20.02.01.01 
    20.02.02 
        20.02.02.01 
        20.02.02.02 
            20.02.02.02.01 
                20.02.02.02.01.01 
            20.02.02.02.02 
            20.02.02.02.03`

Comment: "any simpler solution" than what? What have you tried? Please include this in your question.

Comment: one way could be to count the number of `.` in a given string and space them out accordingly (i.e. One `.` could mean one `\t` etc.)

Comment: Are all the values in the collection unique(set)?

Comment: its not a set, its a List, data without duplicates and in Sorting Order

Comment: First of it is not a decimal number (Can a decimal number have multiple dots?) Iterate through your list. Use regex like `([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})` e.g. `20.01` and extract first five characters and use it as a key to a `HashMap`. No on every subsequent occurrence of `20.01.nn` or `20.01.nn.mm` store them as list to the previous key. In second pass recursively do the same but your regex pattern will become `([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})` and so forth.

Comment: @nabsATX, could you please help me with Code? I am bit poor in Regex

Comment: Is the data set you're given already sorted, and all you have to do is output it? Or are you given an unordered data set that you have to sort, and then output?

Comment: The data will be in Sorted Order.  I just want to have it in Java Object like Node<T,E> where T is List of Child Nodes and E is "label" like in this case it is 20.01.

Answer (score 0):

The input here is a list of labels generated by a depth-first traversal of the tree we're trying to build, where each label describes the full path to a node. Given this, all we actually need is the depth of each node, which can be obtained by counting the number of level-separator characters (`'.'`) in the label.

With this information the original tree can be built using the following algorithm:

```
static int buildTree(TreeNode parent, String[] input, int idx)
{
    TreeNode last = null;       
    while(idx < input.length)
    {
        int depth = input[idx].replaceAll("[^.]", "").length();
        if(depth == parent.depth + 1)
        {
            parent.children.add(last = new TreeNode(input[idx++], depth));
        }
        else if(depth > parent.depth + 1)
        {
            idx = buildTree(last, input, idx);
        }
        else break;
    }
    return idx;
}

static class TreeNode
{
    int depth;
    String label;
    List<TreeNode> children;

    TreeNode(String label, int depth)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.depth = depth;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Testing on the input provided:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] input = {"20.01","20.01.01","20.01.01.01","20.01.02",
            "20.01.02.01","20.01.02.02","20.02","20.02.01","20.02.01.01",
            "20.02.02","20.02.02.01","20.02.02.02","20.02.02.02.01",
            "20.02.02.02.01.01","20.02.02.02.02","20.02.02.02.03"};

    TreeNode root = new TreeNode("", 0);
    buildTree(root, input, 0);
    print(root.children, "");
}

static void print(Collection<TreeNode> children, String ind)
{
    for(TreeNode n : children) 
    {
        System.out.println(ind + n.label);
        print(n.children, ind + "    ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20.01
  20.01.01
      20.01.01.01
  20.01.02
      20.01.02.01
      20.01.02.02
20.02
  20.02.01
      20.02.01.01
  20.02.02
      20.02.02.01
      20.02.02.02
          20.02.02.02.01
              20.02.02.02.01.01
          20.02.02.02.02
          20.02.02.02.03
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to use this approach.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] str_tb={"20.01","20.01.01","20.01.01.01","20.01.02","20.01.02.01","20.01.02.02","20.02","20.02.01","20.02.01.01","20.02.02","20.02.02.01","20.02.02.02","20.02.02.02.01","20.02.02.02.01.01","20.02.02.02.02","20.02.02.02.03"}

        for(str : str_tb){
            int counter = StringUtils.countMatches(str,".")-1;
            while(counter-- != 0){
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure, what you're refering to with "Java object". If you want to have it printed out, this code snipped should solve it.

Comment: The OP is asking for a good Data Structure to store and maintain the object of the kind. It's more or less a technical concept rather than operating with the data itself.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I just want to have it in Java Object like Node<T,E> where T is List of Child Nodes and E is "label" like 20.01.